# Validation of form elements based on usertype

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, zend-framework2

I have two user types in my application. User 1 is admin. User2 are some companies. I have to display a drop down for user1, while I have to by default show the respective company name to the user2 when he tries to use one of the functionalities.

For Admin..when he doesn't chooses any item from drop down..all companies are selected. And for user2 only his data..

How can this be done? In form I tried putting the validations..but it didn't work. Then I tried with it's corresponding phtml file..there also it didn't work. May be I am confused.

Can anyone suggest something on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot for better understanding

Comment: I have a functionality to export data for respective user.
When the companies are logged in..they can download their own data only.
And when the Admin is logged in he can download all the data or data belonging to any particular company.
So for the Admin it will be a drop down..and for the user2(non Admin) it would be a label only with the company name appearing next to Label "Select Company : ".

Okay..Let me share the codes too..

Comment: $idTransporter = $this->createElement('rnoSelect', 'idTransporter',
                    array(
                        'multiOptions' => Transporter ::getListTransporter()
                         )
        );
                     $idTransporter->setLabel('Select Transporter Company ID');
                    // $idTransporter->setRequired(true);
                     if(isset($idTransporter)){
                     $this->addElement($idTransporter);    
                     }

Comment: The above element is for the drop down box. I want to use the session value for the user and validate the user type..and do the functionality make work.
For Admin..I require just a label.